# Spining and movement of electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

Does the electrons spin while exciting from one orbit to another? If they spin how small do they look while spinning comparing to the size when they are in the orbit?

Comment: Both spin and orbital motion are classical metaphors that cannot be interpreted literally when thinking about electrons. Electrons are purely quantum objects that cannot be thought of a

Comment: As localized discrete objects.

Comment: I always hoped they executed a graceful bow after jumping from one orbital to another... Well, except for the cocky electron that thinks its no big deal...

Answer (score 1):

> Does the electrons spin while exciting from one orbit to another?

An electron is always spinning, but not in any classical sense, so it is not a tiny soccer ball in any way that you might imagine. If you think of the word **spin** as meaning something  completely different and completely abstract in  mathematical terms than it does ordinary world physical terms, that is a good starting point.

> If they spin how small do they look while spinning comparing to the size when they are in the orbit?

They don't look **any** size at any time, you are thinking of them as small soccer balls, imagine instead that we can only measure them indirectly, by their charge or other properties, rather than as physical objects.

If you read this [Wikipedia Electron Spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)), it might help, but depending on your background, it might take a good search around the Internet to find an explanation that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the electrons spin while exciting from one orbit to another?

Electrons have an intrinsic property called "spin" which is like their charge. It corresponds to angular momentum in the macroscopic world (the everyday world). They can't lose or gain this spin, so they never stop "spinning".

> If they spin how small do they look while spinning comparing to the size when they are in the orbit?

As far as anyone can measure, the electron is a point particle which has no radius at all, so there is nothing there which is actually "spinning" around. (I don't have a reference for relevant experiments, but will add one when I find it.) If you think of a spinning top, the top is spinning because one side of it is moving one way and the other side is moving the other way. Because an electron, as far as we can see, has no sides or moving parts of any kind, we can't see it spinning. Thus the intrinsic "spin" of the electron is something very mysterious.